# Oracle password regular expression

Tags: regex, oracle11g, passwords, oracle-apex

I want to create a regular expression to verify user's new password for Oracle database.
Conditions:
- at least 8 characters long
- it must begin with a lowercase letter
- it must contain at least 2 digits
- it must contain at least 1 uppercase letter
- underline is the only special character allowed _

This is what I got so far:

```
^(?=[a-z])(?=.*[\d]{2,})(?=.*[A-Z]{1,})[0-9a-zA-Z_]{8,}$
```

Works fine when tested on
[this site.](http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/)
Doesn't work when tested in Oracle with REGEXP_LIKE function.
What's wrong?

Comment: Oracle doesn't support negative/positive look-behinds (or aheads)... why are you arbitrarily restricting your password like this?

Comment: My advice is that you divide the check and use more than one expression.
That way the code will be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Try following.
Length is separately checked.

```
select
    'matched' as STATE
  from DUAL
  where
    length('aAeaasoisd3_f') >= 8 and
    regexp_like('aAeaasoisd3_f', '^[a-z]([0-9a-zA-Z_]*[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z_]*[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z_]*[A-Z][0-9a-zA-Z_]*|[0-9a-zA-Z_]*[A-Z][0-9a-zA-Z_]*[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z_]*[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z_]*|[0-9a-zA-Z_]*[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z_]*[A-Z][0-9a-zA-Z_]*[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z_]*)');
```

Came up with this by dividing the possibilities as

```
^[a-z]X where X could be one of
    ...\d...\d...[A-Z]...
    ...[A-Z]...\d...\d...
    ...\d...[A-Z]...\d...
and ... is [0-9a-zA-Z_]*
```